# Filter the Triage review queue by subject/expertise

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, review-queues, triage

Sometimes I'm having a hard time sifting the Triage requests because I can't seem to filter them on topic. For example, I'm watching C# and SQL Server tagged questions because I have some knowledge of this stuff, so I'm happy to help with Triage if it is about this topic. However when it comes to reviewing Angular, Node.js, Perl, ... it becomes a different story. Is it not possible to filter the review actions as well?

Comment: May I recommend the good, old fashioned **Skip** button?

Answer (score 4):

Triaging should not require any subject-matter expertise. You are only being asked to do a *cursory* evaluation of the question, like [a field medic would triage patients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triage).

We have [a detailed guide to Triage here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295650); as you can see, it says:

> The primary goal of Triage is to *quickly* sort potentially-problematic posts into categories that can be routed elsewhere.

You have three main options:

- **"Looks OK"**: You can think of this as the field medic's equivalent of a **green** tag. The patient is healthy, everything is fine, nothing needs to be done.
- **"Requires Editing"**: You can think of this as the field medic's equivalent of a **yellow** tag. The patient has a chance to survive, but only if he gets some edits. Note that these are edits that *a regular community member* can perform, not edits that need to be made by the asker (for these, see the next category).
- **"Unsalvageable"**: You can think of this as the field medic's equivalent of a **red** tag. The patient is in dire condition and desperately needs attention. This is for questions that need to be closed and/or deleted (for any number of different reasons).

The fourth option—one that you don't get access to as a field medic—is **"Skip"**. This does exactly what it says on the label, and it's meant to be used in cases where you are unsure.

If you really feel like you lack the subject-matter expertise to fairly evaluate a question in Triage, then just "Skip" it.

But we're not going to be adding a subject-matter filter to Triage, because subject-matter expertise should not be required in order to correctly Triage questions, any more than the field medic who triages patients needs to be able to heal all of them.

Comment: My problem with the Triage is that Unsalvageable is also where the votes for dupe or typo are. So, a question mighy *look* like it's OK (decent description, what appears to be context and relevant code, etc) but I may lack the expertise, to recognise it as something that has been asked before or if it's a small problem with the code. And there is an even sneakier one - the question might lack enough details to be answerable. Also close-voteable but also something I might not be able to spot without enough background knowledge. So, it's very hard to say a "foreign" question Looks OK...

Comment: @Cody Gray, it feels like you're assuming I don't have much experience in general given your somewhat schoolish explanation. IMHO it'd be more efficient if I were given some kind of pre-selected choice instead of random stuff (or so it seams). I think I second VLAZ opinion, because I don't like skipping, want to help and just happen to disagree with the "subject-matter expertise should not be required in order to correctly Triage questions" part. So a simple answer of "No" to my question if it is possible or not would have sufficed too. Anyway, that's my 2c for today. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Please don't interpret what I wrote in my answer as patronizing or "schoolish". This is just the way I write. Plenty of veteran SO users don't know how to use the Triage queue or understand its intention. Even if you don't find this summarized guidance useful, others most certainly will. @Thailo

Comment: it's all very well to say "subject matter expertise should not be required", but if i'm skipping 95% of questions, the triage queue is not a good use of my time.

Comment: one of my goals is to try to help answering the questions that I come across.  so i think it would be great to have a filtered triage feature.

Comment: Answering questions is *not* the point of Triage, @Frederick. If you want to answer questions, simply use tag filters and searches.

Comment: @Dave is on the money - I'm happy to help triage cows because I know what they are meant to look like, but when I see a worm, I have no idea if it is ok or not. That would be fine if I only had to skip worms, but I also have to skip trees, trucks and spacecraft. I just skipped 20 in a row, so honestly, I think Triage is not designed for people with narrow skill sets (like me) to help ease the burden on more general experts, which is unfortunate for everyone.

Comment: Can I add my vote to being able to filter the triage queue? I can happily triage questions about SQL, ETL, databases, Snowflake, etc. but questions about websites, java, c++ etc. might as well be in Chinese as far as my ability to triage them is concerned. I've just wasted 10 mins of my life skipping through an endless list of questions that were meaningless to me. If you want people to triage questions you really need to make the process more user-friendly.