# The purpose of "unsalvageable" for triage

Tags: discussion, triage

Suppose a question is mostly good but is just missing a piece of relevant data from the poster (e.g., the poster is asking about an error message in Python but forgot to provide the traceback).  Based on my understanding of the three options for triage, I would click "Unsalvageable" because it "lacks certain detail or clarity".

Perhaps I'm missing what the purpose of the triage review queue is but marking a question as "unsalvageable" seems pretty harsh when a simple comment to the poster about adding information would suffice.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Suppose a question is mostly good but is just missing a piece of relevant data from the poster (e.g., the poster is asking about an error message in Python but forgot to provide the traceback). Based on my understanding of the three options for triage, I would click "Unsalvageable" because it "lacks certain detail or clarity".

That is precisely what you should do, yes.

The post cannot be salvaged by the community—e.g., via editing. The only way to save it is if the original poster makes an edit. Until that time, it needs to be closed.

> Perhaps I'm missing what the purpose of the triage review queue is but marking a question as "unsalvageable" seems pretty harsh when a simple comment to the poster about adding information would suffice.

[The purpose of the Triage review queue is to triage questions quickly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393298/filter-the-triage-review-queue-by-subject-expertise/393300#393300), determining whether they look good as is, whether they need some attention from the community (e.g., an edit), or whether they are lacking information or otherwise unsuited for this site (in which case, they need to be closed).

Closing a question is not "harsh". Questions that lack necessary information should be closed [*as early as possible*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98022/how-soon-should-i-vote-to-close/98026#98026). You can *also* choose to leave a comment, if you like, but a comment itself doesn't solve the problem, so it's not sufficient.

Once the question is edited, it can be re-opened. [In most cases, an edit by the original author will bump such a just-closed question into the reopen review queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256567/which-edits-push-closed-questions-to-the-reopen-review-queue/256572#256572).